# Difference between 'this' and 'self' in programming languages

Tags: oop, keyword, conceptual

In some languages, like Python, we use `self`, but in other languages such as Java, we use `this`.

Is there any special reason for this difference in name for the same function?

Comment: Is there any special reason for any of the differences between languages?  It's just the preferences of the authors.  Any language based on C/C++ syntax is going to use `this` but if you're creating your own syntax then you can use whatever you like.  In VB it's `Me`.

Comment: A lot of them are conversions rather than standard. Self in python can be changed to anything else, as long as it's the first input argument of member method and return value of constructor. Actually, in some less known-to-be OO languages like Matlab, there are almost equal number of programmers that use "self" or "this", simply because half of them learned "self-style" first and others "this-style" first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about the name `self`. It's the name preferred by convention by Pythonistas.

The same goes for Java `this`, nothing special, just the name chosen by convention.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an answer to its full extent.

In PHP `self` is used in `static` class methods while `$this` refers to instantiated object of a non-static class.

EDIT: In java `this` similarly to PHP refers to current object. As for python this answer seems to explain `self` very well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709832/4490187